# Reuse variables globally in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, design-patterns

I have to force these variables to reuse on every one I want to use, which makes me hard. I need to create a class to define these variables and use them in the entire program. How can I do that?

```
string RootFolderName = "Uplaod";
string ProductPictureFolder = "ProductPictureFolder";
string ProductMainPictureFolder = "ProductMainPicture";
string WebRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
string RootPath = Path.Combine(WebRootPath, RootFolderName);
string ProductPicturePath = Path.Combine(WebRootPath, RootFolderName, ProductPictureFolder);
string ProductMainPicturePath = Path.Combine(WebRootPath, RootFolderName, ProductPictureFolder, ProductMainPictureFolder);
string newPath = Path.Combine(WebRootPath, ProductMainPicturePath);
```

Comment: What do you mean by rebuild every time? Can't you use a static class or maybe a singleton class ?

Comment: @MoienTajik i using the static class but it show me error in `_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath` it can not use static class , method or property

Comment: @MoienTajik  Mean `reuse`  My mistake

Comment: As @MoienTajik said, use a static or singleton class. The singleton class will help you access the local variable _hostingEnvironment. If you go with static class, you can pass _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath as a parameter to a method

Comment: @YvesIsrael I do not want to `Class c=new Class()` Class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a singleton class, here you are :

**Interface:**

```
public interface IApplicationData
{
    string RootFolderName { get; }

    string ProductPictureFolder { get; }

    string ProductMainPictureFolder { get; }

    string WebRootPath { get; }

    string RootPath { get; }

    string GetProductPicturePath();

    string GetProductMainPicturePath();

    string GetNewPath();
}
```

**Concrete Implementation:**

```
public class ApplicationData : IApplicationData
{
    readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public ApplicationData(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    public string RootFolderName => "Upload";

    public string ProductPictureFolder => "ProductPictureFolder";

    public string ProductMainPictureFolder => "ProductMainPicture";

    public string WebRootPath => _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;

    public string RootPath => Path.Combine(WebRootPath, RootFolderName);

    public string GetProductPicturePath()
    {
        return Path.Combine(WebRootPath, RootFolderName, ProductPictureFolder);
    }

    public string GetProductMainPicturePath()
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(WebRootPath, RootFolderName, ProductPictureFolder, ProductMainPictureFolder);
        return path;
    }

    public string GetNewPath()
    {
        string productMainPicturePath = GetProductMainPicturePath();
        return Path.Combine(WebRootPath, productMainPicturePath);
    }
}
```

**Registration in DI Container:**

```
services.AddSingleton<IApplicationData, ApplicationData>();
```

**Usage:**

```
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    readonly IApplicationData _applicationData;

    public ValuesController(IApplicationData applicationData)
    {
        _applicationData = applicationData;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        string data = _applicationData.ProductMainPictureFolder;
        string data2 = _applicationData.GetProductPicturePath();
        string data3 = _applicationData.GetNewPath();

        return Ok();
    }
}
```